# MapProxy accessin by Flash Client

Tags: flex, mapproxy

Where can I put the 'crossdomain.xml' file in the MapProxy virtual enviroment ?

[UPDATE] [NEED TAGS for question: mod-wsgi, ogcserver too]
Need to be more specific:

i'm using mapproxy 1.4 in mod-wsgi. 
The same problem I had found in OGCServer (mod-wsgi).
Where have i to put the crossdomain.xml in a mod-wsgi server like Mapproxy or OGCServer?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is in root folder of your webserver environment. This example is working setup for xampp-php-postgresql+geoserver (my personal choice). To bypass flashplayer security restrictions such as to enable access for bitmap manipulation i put this crossdomain policy file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

in these two locations:

```
path for xampp-> xampp_installation_path\htdocs\crossdomain.xml
path for geoserver-> geoserver_installation_path\webapps\root\crossdomain.xml
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to be more specific:

I'm using Mapproxy in mod-wsgi.

Comment: thanks, but it's more complicated in my case. The service is running in mod-wsgi and I tried all the "root" path for crossdomain but none worked.

Comment: i'm not sure, but perhaps you need to manually call the Security.loadPolicyFile() method to tell flash player to request the policy file over http instead of xmlsocket. This [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html) might be useful

Comment: It was only a problem of 'croosdomain.xml' file and a configuration for the ISS/APACHE ..